# Need to remove <span> tag with class = "abc" in JSOUP

Tags: jsoup

I am able to convert document to encoded xml string, parsing document to jsoup.

Facing issue for writing removeSpanTag method to remove any  tag with class="abc-del".

My code so far:

```
// Check for whether element is having content or not
private org.jsoup.nodes.Document removeSpanTags(org.jsoup.nodes.Document document) {
    if (document.body().children().size() > 0) {
        Element startTag = document.body().children().get(0);
        Element endTag = document.body().children().get(document.body().children().size() - 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < listOfTags.size(); i++) {
            if (startTag.toString().trim().equals(listOfTags.get(i).trim())) {
                boolean returnvalue = startTag.toString().contains("ice-del");
                if (returnvalue) {
                    startTag.remove();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Please share some code so people can help you

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
document.select("span.abc").remove();
```

The above line will remove from `document` any `span` element with class `abc`.